Google books api and coil-kt
I'm building a book app in Android Studio using Jetpack Compose, and I'm using the Google Books API to fetch book information and covers. However, when I try to use the image URL from the API with Coil to display the cover, the image doesn’t load. If I use other image URLs (not from Google), Coil displays them fine. Has anyone encountered this issue?
here is a sample of the code:
Image(
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(book.imageUrl),
    contentDescription = book.name,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
        .size(60.dp),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)

I tried AsyncImage and Glide, and I do receive the image URL from the API; the image just doesn’t show up.
I tried a couple of urls, but here’s one: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=-q0reoyIO30C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api

This question is similar to: How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try using an https URL. It should work, tried at my end it is working.
